# How is exchange rate determined in the case of an InterBTC failed redeem?

Tags: parachain, interbtc

The [interlay docs](https://docs.interlay.io/#/vault/overview?id=failed-redeem) state:

> If Vaults fail to behave according to protocol rules, they face
> punishment through liquidation of collateral - specifically, if a
> Vault fails to execute a redeem on time or falls below the liquidation
> collateral threshold.
>
> Failed Redeem If Vaults go offline and fail to execute redeem, there
> are two possible outcomes.
>
> Outcome 1: User retries with another Vault
>
> After the redeem request expires, the user can cancel it and decide to
> retry with another Vault. In this case:
>
> A punishment fee is slashed from the Vaults collateral and paid to the
> user, and A temporary ban is incurred upon the Vault e.g. 24 hours
> from accepting further requests. Outcome 2: User liquidates (part of)
> Vault
>
> After the redeem request expires, the user can cancel it and decide to
> liquidate (part of) the Vault. In this case:
>
> A punishment fee is slashed from the Vaults collateral and paid to the
> user, Vault collateral is slashed at the current spot
> collateral-to-BTC exchange rate and paid to the user, A temporary ban
> is incurred upon the Vault e.g. 24 hours from accepting further
> requests (if it still has collateral left), and The Vault keeps the
> BTC.

How is the "current spot collateral-to-BTC exchange rate" determined? Is there an exchange built into the protocol? If not from where is the rate signal derived?